# DatePicker using CrossRider is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, crossrider

Using CrossRider, I want to add a [`DatePicker`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to page's DOM, here's my code:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.dom.addRemoteCSS('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
    appAPI.dom.addRemoteJS('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js');
    $('<input type="text" id="datepicker" />').prependTo($('body'), function(){$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();});
});
```

But it didn't work, I also tried

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.dom.addRemoteCSS('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
    appAPI.dom.addRemoteJS('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js');
    $('<input type="text" id="datepicker" />').prependTo($('body'));
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

And it didn't work too, and I tried

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.dom.addRemoteCSS('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
    appAPI.dom.addRemoteJS('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js');
    $('<input type="text" id="datepicker" />').prependTo($('body'));
    $('<script>$(function(){$("#datepicker").datepicker();});</script>').appendTo('head');
});
```

But none of them worked, meanwhile if we test this on simple page it will work ?!
For example:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>$(function(){$("#datepicker").datepicker();});</script>
</head>
<body>     
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**How to make the datepicker works using CrossRider ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are interested, here's the solution:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.resources.includeRemoteJS("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js") ;
    appAPI.dom.addRemoteCSS("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css");
    $('<input type="text" id="dateFrom" />').prependTo($('body'));
    $( "#dateFrom" ).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to include jQueryUI is to use Crossrider's native support for jQueryUI via the [appAPI.resources.jQueryUI](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources-method-jQueryUI) method.

Comment: The method `appAPI.resources.jQuery` is also documented. Though, if i use `appAPI.resources.jQuery('1.8.3');` in `appAPI.ready` i get `Uncaught TypeError: appAPI.resources.jQuery is not a function`. Can you help me with this one?